# Query is very very slow on MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am facing this issue since I started to use MariaDB 10 . Queries are taking too much time. With MySql 5.5 they were taking at most one minute to get the result set but with MariaDB I can not even see the result set after 20 minutes.

This system runs on Magento 1.7.0.2 but this problem has nothing to do with Magento so I didn't create it under Magento section.

My server administrator says that "everything is fine on server, queries are running on ram and cpu is 100% when ever this query starts running, if you want to improve it you need to change the query or increase the cpu power.". But I am pretty sure this is related to MariaDB and/or Database server settings.

If there is any one who have faced such an issue before please guide me through the right path to follow.

This is one of the biggest Queries that should run to get data for creating a feed.

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_status`.`value` AS `status`, `at_visibility`.`value` AS      
`visibility`, `at_quality_score`.`value` AS `quality_score`,    
`at_exportable_for_idealo`.`value` AS `exportable`, 
`stock`.`qty`, `stock`.`is_in_stock`, `stock`.`manage_stock`, 
`stock`.`use_config_manage_stock`, `stock`.`min_qty`, 
`stock`.`min_sale_qty`, MAX(DISTINCT request_path) AS `request_path`, 
`cpsl`.`parent_id`, `categories`.*, `categories_parent`.*, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT categories_index.category_id) AS `categories_ids`, 
`price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, 
`price_index`.`tier_price`, `price_index`.`final_price` FROM 
`catalog_product_entity` AS `e`

INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `product_website` ON      
product_website.product_id = e.entity_id AND product_website.website_id =     
'1'

INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON 
(`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` 
= '96') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 0)

INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON 
(`at_visibility`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
(`at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = '102') AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 
0)

INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_quality_score` ON 
(`at_quality_score`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
(`at_quality_score`.`attribute_id` = '313') AND 
(`at_quality_score`.`store_id` = 0)

INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_exportable_for_idealo` ON 
(`at_exportable_for_idealo`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
(`at_exportable_for_idealo`.`attribute_id` = '353') AND 
(`at_exportable_for_idealo`.`store_id` = 0)

LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `stock` ON 
stock.product_id=e.entity_id

LEFT JOIN `core_url_rewrite` AS `url` ON url.product_id=e.entity_id AND 
url.target_path NOT LIKE '%category%' AND is_system=1 AND ISNULL(options) 
AND url.store_id=1

LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_link` AS `cpsl` ON 
cpsl.product_id=e.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `categories` ON 
categories.product_id=e.entity_id

LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `categories_parent` ON 
categories_parent.product_id=cpsl.parent_id

LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `categories_index` ON 
((categories_index.category_id=categories.category_id AND 
categories_index.product_id=categories.product_id) OR 
(categories_index.category_id=categories_parent.category_id AND 
categories_index.product_id=categories_parent.product_id )) AND 
categories_index.store_id=1

LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON 
price_index.entity_id=e.entity_id AND customer_group_id=0 AND 
price_index.website_id=1 WHERE (at_status.value = '1') AND (`e`.`type_id` 
IN('simple')) AND (at_visibility.value IN('1')) AND (`e`.`attribute_set_id` 
IN('19', '13', '4')) AND ((at_quality_score.value = 'A')) AND 
((at_status.value = '1')) AND ((at_exportable_for_idealo.value = '1'))
```

As said I can not see the result even after 20 minutes! No exceptions thrown, no sql error logs, no php error logs, nothing. Even if I run it directly on PhpMyAdmin the result is exactly same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if your dba is saying :"it's running in RAM" - he's not a DBA. He should be saying (if everything is OK) - the query is running on indexes, and the optimisation path looks sane... As for the query itself -- it's horrendous. Anything that isn't a JOIN to indexes should be in the WHERE clause, not in the FROM - that's horrible SQL

Comment: Are all necessary indexes created? This (indexes) takes RAM... Maybe your admin will not say that it runs in RAM after the indexes are created... Missing indexes may have an exponential impact on performance.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, maybe I had to mention that these queries are being created dynamically with respect of selected fields for different feeds on the very same system. This is the reason to have them like separate inner joins. Ram topic is also something normal to use since the queries are being cached on RAM to access them faster later on. The solution for my problem was changing the logic of buffering and using less rows in one query instead of taking them all at once. Still the sql query should work faster with mentioned optimizations. Thanks again for comments.

Comment: It is essentially "wrong" to use `MAX` and `GROUP_CONCAT` and some non-aggregate columns without also having a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for that query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Answer (score -1):

I am not facing this type of issue, but I am sure if you write join with subquery then it will optimize

instead of this

INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `product_website` ON
product_website.product_id = e.entity_id AND product_website.website_id =
'1'

write like

**INNER JOIN
(select * from `catalog_product_website`
 product_website.website_id = '1') as temp
 ON

temp.product_id = e.entity_id**

if you change this in all join this will take less time to execute query.

Comment: And I am sure of the opposite.  Especially in the case of `JOIN ( SELECT... ) JOIN ( SELECT ... )`; that is multiple subqueries.